# query_vars filter not working even though query string parameter is present

Tags: wp-query, filters, query-variable

I am adding a new query string parameter to be passed into the URL so that I can manipulate the REST API responses.

I added this to my `functions.php`

```
add_filter('query_vars', function ($vars) {
        $vars[] = 'xyz';
        return $vars;
});
```

This should make the parameter `xyz` available in the WP_Query object but it does not.

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', function ($query) {
  var_dump($query->query_vars);die;
});
```

The `xyz` property is not available in the `query_vars` however if I dump out the PHP $_GET array, it is there and has the value that I passed in, so I don't know why it wouldn't be making it into the `query_vars`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it quite works like that.  Try inspecting `$query->public_query_vars` instead and I think you'll see it added in there.

The way I usually use it is like this:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_test_query_vars');

function add_test_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = "test";
    return $vars;
}
```

So the same as you but with a named function.

Then I add a rewrite endpoint:

```
function wpse_243396_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'test', EP_PERMALINK );
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse_243396_endpoint' );
```

And after that URLs ending `/test/` set the query var which I test like this:

```
global $wp_query;    
if( isset( $wp_query->query['test'] ) ) { }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Andy. I'm not modifying an endpoint, though. Just trying to get it to recognize a query string parameter like. `wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?xyz=some_value`

Answer (score 0):

I think the value would only be present if you add the get-param to the url when trying to preview it ( or specifically set a value for the query-var using `$query->set()` )

Try adding `?xyz=hello-world` to the end of the url you're testing on & you should see `hello-world` in the dump.

It will also depend on where you dump... maybe try this:

```
add_filter('query_vars', function ($vars) {
        $vars[] = 'xyz';
        return $vars;
});
```

then visit: `yoursite.com/?xyz=hello-world`

```
function trythis( $wp_query ) {
    if ( $wp_query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() ) {
        var_dump( $wp_query ); 
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'trythis' );
```

... & you should see `'xyz'=>'hello-world'` in the dump. I don't think query vars are added to wp-query unless they need to be, that'd add unnecessary bloat.